# Switching from 3x to 2x

Tags: shimano

I have a shimano sora triple crankset and I wanted to change to 2x, I understand I would need new shifters and crankset, is there anything else?
For extra info I have a 9 speed rear derailleur and cassette.
Would the 9 speed affect what crankset I get?

Comment: Changing the shifter might not be necessary: for Acera (the MTB equivalent of Sora), 2x and 3x shifter are mechanically identical, the only difference being the "plastic indicator": the stop on the derailleur itself actually prevents the shifter from engaging the first gear.

Comment: @Renaud Road shifters are different due to the numerous trim positions. MTB shifters just have three positions for the three chainrings. Road double shifters have 2-3 trim positions on top of the 2 main positions. I imagine the triple shifters would have fewer trim positions to avoid having to perform ridiculous amounts of clicking to shift.

Comment: What do you hope to gain with this change ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should get a 9-speed crankset. Preferably, but +-1 is likely to work decently.

The front derailleur is also 2x vs. 3x specific. The 3, has a noticeably bigger inner plate. It is not that expensive sou you should get the 2x one.

You of course have to consider the bottom bracket your new crankset will need. If you have a recent Sora that uses Hollowtech II (most likely RS500), you can buy a crankset that uses the same BB, for example, Sora FC-R3000. If you have an Octalink one, you may find this is the time to upgrade your BB to Hollowtech II to allow the better cranksets.